# How to work with JDBC loaded data in Python

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I'm a data analyst at my company and recently started working on a Zeppelin notebook from Redash.

I would like to work on my SQL loaded data in Python language in the Zeppelin notebook.

Example be like,

%mysql
select column A, column B from tableA

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

%python
pandas.dateframe(aboveresult)

Something like this. I would so much appreciate if anyone knows the trick. I'm kinda lost googling about it.